# How can I find out who's running a certain website? (whois won't tell me)

Tags: hosting, dns, owner

I want to find out who is running a certain website. WHOIS won't tell me - just tells me WhoisGuard Protected. I've found out that the website is hosted on Amazon AWS. Also, I can see the Google Analytics id in the html, if that could help. Is there anyway I can find out who owns it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not. That's what WhoisGuard (and other services are for).

If you have a complaint about the website you need to contact its Hosting provider or the address given by WhoisGuard - but you will not be able to find out "This website belongs to John Malkovich, living in Washington D.C." via any sources if the owner decided to hide the WHOIS information.